# why the thead not showing while displaying data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to ask about my code..
i have made jquery server side function for diplaying data from database into a table. i made the code firstly working well but after i try to add more code for creating a thead before creating the tbody the code wont work..

this is the code i made..
please help me to solve this

```js
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"../php/absen/spl_inputselect_data.php",
  success: function(data){
   var list = JSON.parse(data);
   for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
    
    var tr = "<tr>";
    theadData = '<tr>' +
          '<th>Nama Karyawan</th>' +
           '<th>Tanggal</th>' +
         '<th>Bagian</th>' +
           '<th>Cost Center</th>' +
           '<th>Jam Mulai</th>' +
           '<th>Jam Selesai</th>' +
           '<th>Status Lembur</th>' +
           '<th>Total Jam</th>' +
           '<th>Tugas</th>' +
          '</tr>';
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['nama']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tanggal']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['jam_mulai']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['jam_selesai']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['status']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['total']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['bagian']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['cost']+"</td>";
    tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tugas']+"</td>";
    tr += "</tr>";
    $("#check_data tbody").append(tr);
   }
   return false;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are not appending `theadData` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append your head directly to the table only once and not within the loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/absen/spl_inputselect_data.php",
        success: function(data){
            var list = JSON.parse(data);

            if(list.length > 0)
           {
            $("#check_data thead").html('<tr>' +
                     '<th>Nama Karyawan</th>' +
                     '<th>Tanggal</th>' +
                     '<th>Bagian</th>' +
                     '<th>Cost Center</th>' +
                     '<th>Jam Mulai</th>' +
                     '<th>Jam Selesai</th>' +
                     '<th>Status Lembur</th>' +
                     '<th>Total Jam</th>' +
                     '<th>Tugas</th>' +
                     '</tr>');

            for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){

                var tr = "<tr>";

                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['nama']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tanggal']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['jam_mulai']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['jam_selesai']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['status']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['total']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['bagian']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['cost']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['tugas']+"</td>";
                tr += "</tr>";
                $("#check_data tbody").append(tr);
            }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah... its work.
but why the TH not one line with the Tbody?
it has separate line